# how do l recover files that were removed by make clean in Qt for mac?

Tags: c++, mysql, qt

l recently built mysql drivers in the terminal but ran 'make clean' in the command terminal and they all disappeared.
How do l recover them ?

Comment: Build them again with `make all`. The whole point of `make clean` is to remove all the result files so you can rebuild from scratch.

Comment: If you're on a Mac, you should be able to restore from Time Machine.

Comment: l should learn more about learning from the time machine. l don't know how to do that and l use a mac. And so l just need to run make all in the terminal ?

Comment: And `make install` to install them.

Comment: Thank you so much. l will definitely do that to learn more

Comment: And l have another question, do you Qt and C++?

Comment: No, sorry, I'm not really familiar with Qt.

Comment: Okay then. But thank You so much